# How do i show the result in the HTML page after validation on keypress?

Tags: javascript

I've created a small converter (i'm a total newbie) and I'm trying to make the result appear on the web page.

I've tried going through some YouTube videos along with my Udemy course but I can't seem to make it work.

```js
let convertToInch = function (number){
  if (Number.isInteger(number)){
    return convertedNumber = Math.round(number*0.393700787)
  } else {
    console.log('Not a number')
  }
}

document.querySelector('#conversion').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  convertedNumber = convertToInch(e.target.elements.text.value);
  console.log(convertedNumber);
})
```

```html
<form id="conversion">
  <input type="input" placeholder="Enter Cm" name="text">
  <button>Convert</button>
</form>
```

I would also love to do the conversion as a press a number ,i've tried keypress and i'm getting the following error :

"app.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
    at HTMLFormElement. (app.js:3)"

I've also tried validating the number (so only integers will be processed) using Number.isInteger with an If statement - but i keep on getting the "else" console.log along with "undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert string into number first before using `Number.isInteger`.

[`Number.isInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger) will always return false if the given argument is not typeof number.

Values retrieved from the DOM is always typeof string.

You can convert string into integer using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
let convertToInch = function (number){
  if (Number.isInteger(parseInt(number))){
    return convertedNumber = Math.round(number*0.393700787)
  } else {
    console.log('Not a number')
  }
}

document.querySelector('#conversion').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  convertedNumber = convertToInch(e.target.elements.text.value);
  console.log(convertedNumber);
})
```

```html
<form id="conversion">
  <input type="input" placeholder="Enter Cm" name="text">
  <button>Convert</button>
</form>
```